# How to display a file owned by another thread?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build an application that displays in a GUI the contents of a log file, written by a separate program that I call through subprocess. The application runs in Windows, and is a binary that I have no control over. Also, this application (Actel Designer if anyone cares) will write its output to a log file regardless of how I redirect the output of subprocess, so using a pipe for the output doesn't seem to be an option. The bottom line is that I seem to be forced into reading from a log file at the same time another thread may be writing to it. My question is if there is a way that I can keep the GUI's display of the log file's contents up to date in a robust way?

I've tried the following:

1. Naively opening the file for reading periodically while the child
   process is running causes Python to crash (I'm guessing because the
   child thread is writing to the file while I'm attempting to read its
   contents)
2. Next I tried to open a file handle to the log filename before invoking the child process with GENERIC_READ, and SHARED_READ | SHARED_WRITE | SHARED_DELETE and reading back from that file. With this approach, the file appears empty

Thanks for any help you can provide - I'm not a professional programmer and I've been pulling my hair out over this for a week.

Comment: So the thread generating the log file has control over when the file is updated? If that's the case, get your updating thread to pause what it is doing while your reading thread reads in the file, then close the file in the reading thread and let the updating thread update again. Another thought: have the file owned by a third thread and get the first two threads to ask that third thread for any info they need.

Comment: The log file is generated by 3rd party software that I have no control over - it is a .exe file on the computer. When it is launched from the command line (or subprocess) it immediately spawns another thread. It sounds like what you're describing would require control of that spawned thread, and I don't see a way to achieve that (open to suggestions though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register for notifications on file change, the way [`tail -f`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) does (you can find out what system calls it uses by executing `strace tail -f logfile`).

[pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) provides a Python interface for these file change notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I don't think pyinotify will work with Windows, but I did find another module that seems to do something similar called Watchdog (http://packages.python.org/watchdog/). I'm going to learn how to use that and let you know if this approach works

Comment: Using a file notification-based solution (Watchdog) solved my problem.